# Android types "vnd.android"

Tags: android, mime-types

1. What means vnd.android (vnd.android.cursor.dir)?
2. Where can I find full list and description about this types?

I found this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type but this is not a complete list. Please give any link of full media type list.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `vnd.` prefix on a MIME type is a "vendor prefix", meaning that it is not an official IETF MIME type.

`vnd.android.cursor.dir` is part of a faux MIME type used for database-style `ContentProviders` in Android, specifically for `Uri` values that map to what logically would be considered "tables" or "views" (collections of content). For example, [the AOSP Contacts application](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/) has activities that will respond to a MIME type of `vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact`. You can find various other uses of `vnd.android` by filling that into the search field in [the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=vnd.android).

> Where can I find full list and description about this types?

There is none that I am aware of. Vendor-prefixed MIME types can be used or defined by anyone.